# LPCWSTR issue in C I suppose, Program is crashing

Tags: c, user-input, createprocess

I'm trying to take user input and use that in the CreateProcessW() function. Simply put, the user puts in the path of the application and the program opens it up. But it's crashing. Any help. Everything compiles fine.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <errno.h>



void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    LPCWSTR drive[2];

    printf("\nEnter the drive, do not include '\\' (Ex. C:) : ");
    wscanf(L"%s", drive);

    LPCWSTR path = L"\\Windows\\notepad.exe";

    STARTUPINFOW siStartupInfo; 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo; 

    memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo)); 
    memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 

    siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo); 

    LPCWSTR pPath;

    wprintf(L"%ls%ls\n", drive, path);
    printf("\nPlease enter the path exact as shown above: ");
    wscanf(L"%s", &pPath);

    printf("\nNow opening notepad . . . . \n\n");
    delay(3000);

    if (CreateProcessW(pPath, 
                        NULL, 
                        NULL, 
                        NULL, 
                        FALSE, 
                        0, 
                        NULL, 
                        NULL, 
                        &siStartupInfo, 
                        &piProcessInfo)) 
    {
        printf("Notepad opened. . .\n\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Error = %ld\n", GetLastError());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

BTW most of the code is compromised up snippets I found online and here.

Answer (score 0):

```
LPCWSTR drive[2];
```

You allocate space for two pointers.

```
printf("\nEnter the drive, do not include '\\' (Ex. C:) : ");
wscanf(L"%s", drive);
```

Ooops, you're telling `wscanf` to store a string in the space you allocated. But you only allocated space for two pointers.

```
LPCWSTR pPath;
```

Okay, `pPath` is a pointer that doesn't yet point to anything. All you have is one pointer.

```
wscanf(L"%s", &pPath);
```

You were supposed to tell `wscanf` where to store the string that is being input. But you never allocated space for a string, you just created a pointer that doesn't point to anything.

Here's some code from the first example of `wscanf` that I could find:

```
  wchar_t str [80];
  int i;

  wprintf (L"Enter your family name: ");
  wscanf (L"%ls",str);
```

Notice how it allocates space for an array of 80 wide characters and then tells `wscanf` to store the input in the array of characters?